# wrong git repo owner

Tags: git, repository, permission-denied

I try push a local repo to github and get such a message:

```
The remote end hung up unexpectedly.

ERROR: Permission to [repo_name] denied to [user_name]
```

But I can't understand where it finds such a name. I have 2 ones on my local computer but for this repo I had set another name for the project explicitly,

```
cd project_directory
```

both, 
local:

```
git config user.name [right_user_name]
```

and global:

```
git config --global user.name [right_user_name]
```

...user name.
But it nevertheless thinks that a real name is [user_name] but not [right_user_name].
Please help me to find the cause of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In github, the authentication is solely done using SSH keys. So, whichever SSH key you are sending is used by github to find which account you are associated with, and that's where "username" comes from.

The git username is only used when you create new commits. Since a given person can push commits from anybody, it cannot be used by github for access rights (that would not be secure anyway ...)

Comment: Thank you. But the problem still remains unresolved. I already have a SSH key on my github account. And when I try to make push it asks me username and password.
1. Why it does so?
2. It doesn't recognize me even I point my username and password out.
:(
Hope to get some idea...

Comment: Also here is following:
When I make a command $ ssh -T git@github.com (as pointed at github help) it says:
Hi serge-serg! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
What may it mean?

Comment: Sorry about the preview issue, I should just go further.
So I did all that github recommended. I stopped at https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey.
I make the command: ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
The fingerprint matches. But I got a message "fatal: Authentication failed" again... :(